# How to print in the same format as the python console

Tags: python, formatting

I am working with 3D arrays, for example, in an IPython console:

```
In [8]: xx = [[[0 for i in range(4)] for j in range(4)] for k in range(4)]

xx
Out[9]: 
[[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]]

print(xx)
[[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]]
```

When I just evaluate the array in the console it is nicely formatted, but when I print() it, it formats in one long line which then wraps and looks horrible. There are long-winded ways to reproduce the terminal-style formatting from within a program, but is it possible to just call the function that formats for the console directly? I tried

```
repr(xx)
```

But that does not have the desired effect. Such a function could be generally useful, not just for arrays.

Comment: `from pprint import pprint; pprint(xx)`

Comment: There is no (easy) way to see what it exactly looked like in the source code, but you may want to check out `pprint`. (see [the docs](https://www.google.com/search?q=pprint+python&oq=pprint+python&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2237j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html), like the below:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(xx)
[[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]]
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks U9 and Ethan. pprint does what I want. I'm guessing the console itself uses pprint for formatting.

Comment: @gareth I guess too. Happy to help, :-), 